# onclick event on li tag

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to display some items on basis of their categories. Here is my code.

```
$cat=array("all","coding","registry","analytics");
    list($a,$b,$c,,$d)=$cat;
    $members .='<ul>';
    $members .='<li onclick="case_studies_get_some($a)">All</li>';
    $members .='<li onclick="case_studies_get_some($b)")">Coding</li>';
    $members .='<li onclick="case_studies_get_some($c)">Registry</li>';
    $members .='<li onclick="case_studies_get_some($d)">Analytics</li>';
    $members .='</ul>';



return $members;

    $output .= '<ul class="team-members-list">';
    foreach( $members as $member ) {
        $output .= case_studies_display_one( $member );
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}
```

By clicking on particular tag it should call following function

```
function case_studies_get_some(&$cat){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "case_studies";

        $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name where category = %s ORDER BY name",
                                     $cat);
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );

    $results = array();
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
        $row['image'] = $row['imageloc'];
        $row['website'] = $row['url'];
        unset( $row['imageloc'] );
        array_push( $results, $row );
    }

    return $results;
}
```

But it is not working. I think onclick event is not working..
Any suggestions please..

Comment: Why are you putting $ before every variable? Why are you using ->?

Comment: it is for wordpress database prefix. where should i not put $?

Comment: You can't have a two return statements for a single function

Comment: All that code is PHP, not Javascript. It runs on the server, not in the browser. It creates HTML that is later loaded/run in the browser, but `onclick` events can't touch it.

Comment: Ah This question needs to be re-tagged

Comment: check your logic..., check for errors also. selecting database for each item is a waste of ... time (at least)

Answer (score 4):

Here is error

```
//This is php function
function case_studies_get_some(&$cat)
{

}
```

remember onclick event accept only javascript function. you are using php function above.

Comment: Thanks leftclickben :)

Comment: Ok i am calling javascript function by onclick event, then i have to call case_studies_get_some function in that javascript function?

Comment: I am unable to find **case_studies_get_some()** function which you have define in onlick event.   You have mentioned **case_studies_get_some()** but this is php function

Comment: Chinmay , what i have to do is retrieve results from php function case_studies_get_some by clicking on li element by passing elements of array to it. what should i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, variables within 'single-quoted strings' are not replaced by their values (this only happens in "double-quoted strings").  You also need to quote that value in the JavaScript.  So you need to use:

```
$members .= '<li onclick="case_studies_get_some(\'' . $a . '\')">All</li>';
```

This will produce output like:

```
<li onclick="case_studies_get_some('all')">All</li>
```

There are possibly other problems but this is the one most immediately related to the `onclick` event.